# Cannot hear my notification sound on my Samsung Galaxy On5?

Tags: audio, notifications

Okay, so I got my new phone (A Samsung Galaxy On5) about 2 months ago, and just recently, the notification sound stopped working. I checked to make sure that it wasn't on silent or vibrate, and it's not. The sound is on, and ringtone is on too, but ringtone is the call sound. Instead of emitting a sound for my notification, it just vibrates. I've tried powering it down and back on again, but nothing seems to work. Help?

Comment: AskDifferent: "Answers for your **Apple** questions"

Comment: Ringtone doesn't work too?